# Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view in Django RestFramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return a response after the execution of loop but I'm getting an error as

```
AssertionError at Data/CurrentRunningActivityForAudit/10 
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

when I added another return response outside the loop it shows the empty array i.e.,.[ ] it's returning empty response

`

views.py:

```
def CurrentRunningActivity(UserID):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivityAudit] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()

        IsActive = 'true'
     
        for row in result_set:
         data = []
         data.append({
            'TaskId':row[0],           
            'TaskName' : row[1],
            'Source' : row[2],
            'Requester' : row[3],
            'type' : row[4],
            'IsActive':IsActive,

         })
           
        
         return Response(data[0], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

when I move the return response outside the loop it shows as `local variable 'data' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Your response is inside your loop. If `result_set` is empty, no loop will be triggered. Then no response will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You've to change your code like this

```
def CurrentRunningActivity(UserID):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivityAudit] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()

    IsActive = 'true'
    data = [] # changed
    for row in result_set:
        data.append({
          'TaskId':row[0],           
          'TaskName' : row[1],
          'Source' : row[2],
          'Requester' : row[3],
          'type' : row[4],
          'IsActive':IsActive,

        })
           
        
     return Response(data[0], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def CurrentRunningActivity(UserID):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetCurrentRunningActivityAudit] @UserId=%s',(UserID,))
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()

    IsActive = 'true'
    data = []
    for row in result_set:
        data.append({
            'TaskId': row[0],           
            'TaskName' : row[1],
            'Source' : row[2],
            'Requester' : row[3],
            'type' : row[4],
            'IsActive': IsActive,
         })

    return Response(
        data[0] if data else [],
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
```